# Use of Page_PreRender to execute C# code when page controls are loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string runat = "runat=\"server\"";    
}

protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
//some code       
}

<iframe <%=runat%>></iframe>
```

I need to be sure the code within `Page_PreRender` executes only when the variable runat has been initialized & the `iframe` control is ready for rendering.
Unfortunately it does not work. I also tried `Page_PreRenderComplete` and it does not work.

Does anyone have an idea to fix this problem ?
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe take a look at this post? http://stackoverflow.com/a/27041430/3231537

Comment: thank you but i'm using .NET v3.5

Comment: I think you misunderstand the ASP.NET page life cycle. Page_PreRender occurs after Page_Load. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: Why are you trying to create a server control by using a code block? I don't think what you're trying to do is possible. Why not just set the runat="server" attribute on the iframe element at design time? Then you could get access to all of the controls on the page in the Page_Load event.

Comment: Jacob Heater : Indeed, that's easier but i'm using a CMS which does not allow those attributes easily. I have no other choice than doing it that way unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Create a `PlaceHolder` in your markup and then add the `iframe` programmatically to the `PlaceHolder` as a `LiteralControl`, like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<iframe src='something.aspx'></iframe>"));
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the iframe comes directly from the CMS and i have no possibility to insert it in C#

Comment: How does it come from the CMS?