# Trying to push contents into IFRAME from VB.NET code behind (no success)

Tags: vb.net, iframe

In my HTML document I have an iframe within an iframe. The outside iframe loads an ASPX page with code behind in VB.NET that produces a result from a DB query. For some reasons that are beside the point I need to push the result produced within the inner iframe (whith id="iresults"):

```
<iframe id="iresults" runat="server" />
```

In my VB.NET code behind I tried ('output' is the string variable containing HTML code):

```
iresults.innerHTML = output
iresults.innerText = output
iresults.Attributes("innerHTML") = output
iresults.Attributes("innerText") = output
iresults.Attributes("srcdoc") = output
```

However no one of these attempts worked (nothing changed into the "iresults" iframe). Any idea?

*PS: The 'output' variable contains data!*

Comment: There is a good discussion of iframe at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015070/using-iframes-in-asp-net which also provides additional links.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mary, it was of great help!